# I am unable to load static files in django although i have done everything

Tags: django, static

[image]in my settings.py file i did

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION='static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR=[
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Kevin/static')
]
STATIC_ROOT='static'
```

but in my templates i am unable to load the files
the template folder is in root directory
whereas static folder is in django root folder named as Kevin which is also in that base folder
in my html template i did the

```
{% load static %}
```

i am sharing some code of my template as well so you can have a look
[image]
{% load static %}

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Kevin - Dashboard</title>

<!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
<link href="{% static 'vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'%}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
    rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template-->
<link href="{%static 'css/sb-admin-2.min.css'%}" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image]

Comment: Did you run **python manage.py collectstatic** ?

Comment: Is it in your dev environnement or in production ?

Comment: Maybe you can provide a screenshot of your project tree structure to help us better understand ?

Comment: show your main **urls.py** code @Azee

Comment: @GaëtanGR yup i did that twice

Comment: @c.grey  i have added screenshot kindly let me know

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a static URL in urls.py also

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
   .....
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: didn't make any difference

Comment: add in URLs where your settings.py is located @Azee

Comment: you don't need to add this if you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, which I guess you have.

Comment: @c.grey i already added those in my base urls.py but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
 STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "myappname/static",

 ]
```

this solved for me basically i misspelled the above code
i used STATICFILES_DIR instead of STATICFILES_DIRS